# QML Flickable scrollbar change color fills the whole handle

Tags: qml

I have the following QML where I'm trying to change the scrollbar handle color. The color changes but it just fills the whole scrollbar and the handle does not move anymore while scrolling. Removing the color makes the scrollbar look correct again.

How can I change the color while keeping the handle moving

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls

Flickable {
    property bool scrollVisible;
    property int columns : 3
    
    id: slidesFrame
    anchors.fill: parent
    clip:true
    flickDeceleration :10000
    boundsMovement: Flickable.StopAtBounds
    
    contentHeight: slidesFlowView.childrenRect.height + slidesFlowView.parent.anchors.margins
    
    
    ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
        id:control
        
        onVisibleChanged: {
            slidesFrame.scrollVisible = visible
        }
        contentItem: Rectangle {
            implicitWidth: 10
            color: control.pressed ?  "#3C73AE" : "#424242"
            
        }
        background: Rectangle {
            color:"#6D6D6D"
        }
        
    }
    
    
    Rectangle{
        color:"#1E1E1E"
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 12
        
        Flow {
            id: slidesFlowView
            anchors.fill: parent
            spacing: 14
            Repeater{
                model : GPresenter.slides
                SlidePreview{
                    width: {
                        const scrollWidth = slidesFrame.scrollVisible ? control.width/slidesFrame.columns : 0
                        return (parent.width/slidesFrame.columns) - ((parent.spacing/slidesFrame.columns) * (slidesFrame.columns-1)) - scrollWidth
                    }
                }
                
                
            }
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

[image]

Here it is below without the color change looking correctly

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that if you comment out this line: `color: control.pressed ?  "#3C73AE" : "#424242"` then everything looks correct?

Comment: @JarMan If I take the whole `contentItem: Rectangle` part then scrollbar handle looks correct but then I'm not changing the color

Comment: Are you expecting those Up and Down arrow buttons to remain?